# Node.js continuation-local-storage usage

Tags: node.js

server.js

```
var Session = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace('session')

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
// create a new context and store request object
Session.run(function() {
    Session.set('req', req);
    next()
  })
});
```

other-module.js

```
var Session = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace('session')

Session.get('req') // returns 'undefined'
```

How to get data from continuation-local-storage when to context is already not active?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been long time but I am adding the answer for the benefit of people coming accross this question.

This is the way I am using it:
to set

```
var session = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace('session')
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    session.bindEmitter(req);
    session.bindEmitter(res);

    session.run(function() {
      session.set('req', req);
      next();
    });
  });
```

to get is the same as in the question

```
var session = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace('session')
session.get('req')
```