# concurrent request for continuation-local-storage module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Node js continuation-local-storage to store unique ID for each request

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   var tid = uuid.v4();
   var pre_ip;
      if(get_ip(req))
      { ip_info= get_ip(req).clientIp;
          pre_ip=ip_info
      }
      namespace.bindEmitter(req);
      namespace.bindEmitter(res);
    namespace.run(function() {
           console.log(logobj);
          namespace.set('tid', tid);
          namespace.set('ip',ip_info);
       namespace.set('logobj',logobj);   
          next();
      });
  });
```

But if concurrent request come will it able to show the correct tid to me.If yes then how.

Comment: see my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/a/34159525/312929